# tikz-cd: extra gray line with Rightarrow

Tags: tikz-arrows, tikz-cd

At first I thought this was a problem of my pdf viewer. For example, with the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A & B
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

The resulting `Rightarrow` seems to contain two small extra gray lines:

[image]

The problem has been addressed in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642548/194994) a few months ago, where the author  provided a complicated new style `nRightarrow` which appears to fix the problem (`Rightarrow` above, `nRightarrow` below):

[image]

However, the need for this new style `nRightarrow` mainly seems to come from other more complicated issues. Thus I would like to know that just for the problem of these two extra gray lines, is there an existing simpler solution by now?

Below is a MWE, in which I have copied the code of `nRightarrow` from the linked question.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\newlength{\eqoffset}
\makeatletter
% relative coordinates: (0,0) is the arrow's tail, x points towards the head,
% y points perpendicular, unit distance is \eqoffset
\newcommand{\relptstart}[2]{($($(k0)!#1*\eqoffset+\pgf@shorten@start@additional!0:(k1)$)!#2*\eqoffset!90:(k1)$)}
% (0,0) is the arrow's tip, rest is the same
\newcommand{\relptend}[2]{($($(k1)!#1*\eqoffset-\pgf@shorten@end@additional
    -2*\eqoffset-.5*\pgflinewidth!180:(k0)$)!#2*\eqoffset!-90:(k0)$)}
\tikzcdset{
    nRightarrow/.style={line join=round,
    no head,
    /tikz/commutative diagrams/@shiftabletopath,
    execute at begin to = {
        % Do not use tikzcd@noda or tikzcd@x here, it causes interference.
        % Use new names instead
        \path (\tikztostart) -- (\tikztotarget) coordinate[pos=0] (k0) coordinate[pos=1] (k1);
        \pgfpointnormalised{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfpointanchor{k1}{center}}{\pgfpointanchor{k0}{center}}}
        \pgfgetlastxy{\kdx}{\kdy}
        \tikzset{
        to path={
            % arrow body
            % the .06 is from \pgftransformxshift{.06\pgfutil@tempdima}
            \relptstart{0}{1}
            -- \relptend{-.06}{1}
            {
                % correct vertical position, more central horizontal position
                %               [xshift=-\kdy*\eqoffset, yshift=\kdx*\eqoffset]
                % matches original Rightarrow more closely
                [xshift=-\kdy*\eqoffset-\kdx*(\eqoffset+.25*\pgflinewidth),
                yshift=\kdx*\eqoffset-\kdy*(\eqoffset+.25*\pgflinewidth)] 
                \tikztonodes}
            \relptstart{0}{-1}
            -- \relptend{-.06}{-1}
            % arrow tip
            % fake the round cap by using round joins and drawing the path twice with a turnaround at the caps
            \relptend{2}{0}         % tip to top end
            .. controls \relptend{1}{0.05} and \relptend{-0.75}{1.25} ..
            \relptend{-1.4}{2.65}   % top end back to tip
            .. controls \relptend{-0.75}{1.25} and \relptend{1}{0.05} ..
            \relptend{2}{0}         % tip to bottom end
            .. controls \relptend{1}{-0.05} and \relptend{-0.75}{-1.25} ..
            \relptend{-1.4}{-2.65}  % bottom end back to tip
            .. controls \relptend{-0.75}{-1.25} and \relptend{1}{-0.05} ..
            \relptend{2}{0}
            % Add a degenerate path segment at the end so shorten < and shorten > are not applied again
            (k1)
        }}
    }}
}
\setlength{\eqoffset}{.225ex}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    A & B
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\begin{tikzcd}[column sep=large]
    A & B
    \arrow[nRightarrow, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The simplest solution would be to use another PDF renderer/viewer that doesn't let that sliver of black shine through.

Comment: Have you noticed that the linked questions spawned off a [lengthy discussion](https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/issues/14#issuecomment-1362929005) about this topic with the author of `tikz-cd` and implementation of how to draw parallel curves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The linked question spanwed off a [lengthy discussion](https://github.com/astoff/tikz-cd/issues/14#issuecomment-1362929005) with the author of TikZ-CD on how to re-implement parallel lines. The code seems to be almost [finished on a PGF level](https://github.com/pgf-tikz/pgf/issues/1226).

Short of reimplementing the way PGF draws `double` lines here is a proof of concept on how to slightly alter the way PGF draws the `double` lines

- either by lengthening the inner line
- or by shortening the outer line.

This is far from perfect but works best for

- straight lines
- that consists of one segment (only one move to at the start),
- aren't dashed and use the normal `rect` line cap.

In addition it'd be best if the arrows don't touch drawn nodes.

The `spath3` library could help in making the (un)shortening not distort the curve and could also help in applying this to paths that have more than one segment.

### Code

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\makeatletter
\def\pgf@double@cheat#1{%
  \let\pgf@tips@mode\pgf@tips@mode@false
  \pgfsetarrowsstart{}\pgfsetarrowsend{}%
  \pgfsetshortenstart{#1}\pgfsetshortenend{#1}%
  \pgf@prepare@end@of@path\pgf@prepare@start@of@path}
\pgfset{
  shorten outer/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{#1}%
    \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/shorten outer}{\the\pgfutil@tempdima},
  shorten outer=+0pt,
  unshorten inner/.code=%
    \pgfmathsetlength\pgfutil@tempdima{#1}%
    \pgfkeyssetevalue{/pgf/unshorten inner}{\the\pgfutil@tempdima},
  unshorten inner=+0pt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\patchcmd{\pgf@stroke@inner@line}{\pgfsyssoftpath@invokecurrentpath}{%
    \ifdim\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/unshorten inner}>0pt
      \pgf@double@cheat{-\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/unshorten inner}}%
    \fi\pgfsyssoftpath@invokecurrentpath}{}{\PatchFailed}

\patchcmd{\pgfusepath}{\fi\pgfsyssoftpath@invokecurrentpath\pgf@up@action}{%
  \fi \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt
        \ifdim\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shorten outer}>0pt
          \pgfgetpath\pgf@temppath
          \pgf@double@cheat{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shorten outer}}\fi\fi
      \pgfsyssoftpath@invokecurrentpath%
      \ifdim\pgfinnerlinewidth>0pt
        \ifdim\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgf/shorten outer}>0pt
          \pgfsetpath\pgf@temppath\fi\fi\pgf@up@action}{}{\PatchFailed}
\makeatother
\newcommand*\everycell[1]{%
  \draw[cd=Rightarrow,#1]node(A){$A$}node(B)at(2,0){$B$}(A)to(B);}
\begin{document}
\tikz[
  cd/.code=\tikzcdset{#1}, anchor=base,
  cd dbl/.style={cd={background color=green}},
  cells={nodes={behind path, help lines, draw, shape=asymmetrical rectangle}},
  column 1/.append style={anchor=base west, nodes=path only},
  rows/.style args={#1 => #2}{row #1/.append style={#2}},
  rows/.list={2 => unshorten inner = .05pt,
              3 => shorten outer = .05pt,
              4 => {cd dbl=green, unshorten inner = 2pt},
              5 => {cd dbl=green, shorten outer = 2pt}}
]\matrix[column sep=\tabcolsep]{
 \node{normal:};        & \everycell{} & \everycell{bend left} \\
 \node{inner:};         & \everycell{} & \everycell{bend left} \\
 \node{outer:};         & \everycell{} & \everycell{bend left} \\
 \node{extreme inner:}; & \everycell{} & \everycell{bend left} \\
 \node{extreme outer:}; & \everycell{} & \everycell{bend left} \\};

\begin{tikzcd}[unshorten inner=+0.01pt]
    A & B
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-1, to=1-2]
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

### Output

In this case, it is best to compile yourself and look at the output in various zoom levels and with different PDF viewers/renderers. Still, you can click in the first two images to view a bigger version of it.

[image][image: as above but with drawn nodes]

[image]

Comment: Thank you for spreading the word! The discussion has now concluded in me publishing [tikz-nfold](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-nfold), I have updated [my question here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/642548/191686) as well.

Comment: @Jonathan I've got a GitHub notification about the issue on the tikz-cd repo. Feel free to add an answer with your library (doesn't need to be on CTAN) here and also self-answer your own question.

Answer (score 5):

I wrote [tikz-nfold](https://ctan.org/pkg/tikz-nfold) specifically to solve this problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
\usetikzlibrary{nfold}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}
    A & B
    \arrow[Rightarrow, from=1-1, to=1-2, nfold]
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

On a side note, the author of `tikz-cd` recently [informed me](https://github.com/jonschz/tikz-nfold/issues/1#issue-1640504369) that `\usepackage{tikz-cd}` is a legacy feature, though there is nothing wrong with using it.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `xy` package for commutative diagram there is not vertical line or  parallel line  in the tail of the arrow.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[all,cmtip]{xy}

\begin{document}
\xymatrix@C=3pc{A \ar@{=>}[r]& B}
\end{document}
```

[image]